# Getting java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name with hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

Getting java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name even though column with same name are in table. what can be a reason?
I am trying to call sp with below code:

```
 Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Query query = session.getNamedQuery("EMPLOYEE.PRC_HB_EMP_SP1");
                    query.setParameter("IN_EMPID", empId);

              List<Employee> empList = query.list();
              System.out.println(empList);
```

Entity class Employee:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
    //@org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery(name = "EMPLOYEE.PRC_HB_EMP_SP1", query = "call PRC_HB_EMP_SP1(?,:IN_EMPID)", callable = true, resultClass = Employee.class)
    @org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery(name = "EMPLOYEE.PRC_HB_EMP_SP1", query = "call PRC_HB_EMP_SP1(?,:IN_EMPID)", callable = true, resultClass = Employee.class)

    public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -723583058586873479L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "EMPID")
    private Integer empId;
    @Column(name = "EMPNAME")
    private String empName;
    @Column(name = "ADDRESS")
    private String empAddress;
    @Column(name = "SALARY")
    private Long salary;
    @Column(name = "EMPAGE")
    private Integer empAge;
............
}
```

here is sp:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE PRC_HB_EMP_SP1
(
  Out_value OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
  IN_EMPID  NUMBER
)
AS

BEGIN

   open Out_value for
    SELECT EMPID,EMPNAME 
            FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE  EMPID = IN_EMPID;

END PRC_HB_EMP_SP1;
```

Stacktrace:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [sdnext] in context with path [/sdnext] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:134)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:179)
    at oracle.jdbc.dbaccess.DBError.throwSqlException(DBError.java:269)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.get_column_index(OracleStatement.java:5971)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1527)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:1482)
    at org.hibernate.type.StringType.get(StringType.java:18)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:81)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2101)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1380)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1308)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1206)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:580)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
    at com.dineshonjava.controller.EmployeeController.getEmployeeDetail(EmployeeController.java:160)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:436)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:424)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: @Downvoter: why downvote for this? nothing is available on net for this. if you have solution or link related to it  then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Your mappings contain columns ADDRESS,SALARY and EMPAGE but those are missing from your SP.You need to include those in your statement.

Comment: which statement? i added those columns in sp. but still error is coming